# Get variable from out of Class OOP PHP

Tags: php, oop

I wanna get variable from out of class.

Example,

config.php

```
$config['function'] = array('filter_validate','form');
```

controller.php

```
class Controller{

   public function __construct()
   {
       foreach ($config['function'] as $key => $function_class) {
          $function_class = new $function_class();
       }       
   }

}
```

But, I can't get $config['function'] variable in Controller. How can do that?

Comment: Pass it as a `parameter`

Comment: Or make config class

Comment: Take a look at very basic tutorials first...

Comment: Thanks @bub for advice.

Comment: There are many ways, the most modern right now is with a fluent, getter / setter. Like:
    public function config(array|string $arg, array|string $default) 
    {
    // assume arg is a getter
    if(is_string($arg)) return $this->variableBag[$arg];
    // assume arg is a setter when array
    if(is_array($arg)) return $this->variableBag[$arg] = $arg[1] ?? $arg['value'] ?? 
    $arg['set'];
    }

Answer (score 1):

**Solution #1 (with parameter):**

```
class Controller {
    public function __construct($config) {
        foreach ($config['function'] as $key => $function_class) {
          $function_class = new $function_class();
       }       
   }
}
```

**Solution #2 (with [global](http://php.net/manual/de/language.variables.scope.php) - NOT recommended):**

```
class Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        global $config;
        foreach ($config['function'] as $key => $function_class) {
          $function_class = new $function_class();
       }       
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass config to the constructor, like this:

```
class Controller{

   public function __construct($config)
   {
       foreach ($config['function'] as $key => $function_class) {
          $function_class = new $function_class();
       }       
   }

}

$config['function'] = array('filter_validate','form');
$controller = new Controller($config);
```

Answer (score 0):

functions outside any class are global an can be called from anywhere. The same with variables.. just remember to use the global for the variables.

```
<?php   
    function abc() {  }

    $foo = 'bar';

    class SomeClass {
        public    function tada(){
            global $foo;
            abc();
            echo 'foo and '.$foo;  
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, the most modern right now is with a fluent, getter / setter. one one of many examples, not tested:

````php
    public function config(array|string $arg, array|string $default) 
    {
        // assume lonley arg is a getter
        if(is_string($arg)) return $this->variableBag[$arg];
        // assume arg is a setter when array
        if(is_array($arg)) return $this->variableBag[$arg[0]??$arg['key'] = ?? $arg['1'] ?? $arg['value'];
        // else assume if second is set a default val
        return isset($this->variableBag[$default]) ?$this->variableBag[$default] : $default
    }
    ```
````